# A complex type without an element in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

Is it possible to define an XSD having only complex types without xs:elements?

Something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xml:lang="en" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:complexType name="complexType1">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="element1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element name="element2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Or do we have to include at least a single xs:element of the defined complex type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it is possible. There is no requirement to always have an element of that type.

To answer the question of @RabvidDog5150, why would someone want this, there may be a number of reasons.

- Your complex type may be *abstract* (abstract base types which some other types will derive from later on).
- Your schema may be some kind of a "base schema", other schemas will import and extend it.
- Even if there are no elements in the schema, you can still do something like `<someElement xsi:type="urn:complexType1">...</someElement>`. This will instruct a schema-aware processor to process the `someElement` element as `complexType1` type.

Comment: could you please add complete example about the last option?